# myBatis3.1.1 XML file about update statement

Tags: mybatis

I made a mapper XML file like this:

```
<update id="feeCalculation" parameterType="map">
 declare @cnt int

insert into #tempA
select ... from ... where ...

insert into #tempA
select ... from ... where ...

insert into #tempB
select ... from ... where ...

insert into #tempB
select ... from ... where ...

insert into #tempC ...

select @cnt=count(*) from #tempA where ...

if @cnt &gt; 0

begin 

insert into #tempD ...

update #tempA set...

update #tempA set...

update #tempB set...

update #tempD set...

end

update #tempC set...

</update>
```

Because the calculation involves many steps working with several session temp tables, I put them all in one transaction. The result will be in #tempC and #tempD which will be fetched by next call.

With 'normal' data size, it works well by a single call 'feeCalculation()'. But when the data size increased, I encountered an error -- it failed somewhere in the middle so it got rollback without any exception thrown (I had try {} catch {} with the call).   When I splited the single call into two calls, it worked:

```
<update id="feeCalculation1" parameterType="map">

declare @cnt int

insert into #tempA
select ... from ... where ...

insert into #tempA
select ... from ... where ...

insert into #tempB
select ... from ... where ...

insert into #tempB
select ... from ... where ...

insert into #tempC ...

</update>
<update id="feeCalculation2" parameterType="map">

select @cnt=count(*) from #tempA where ...

if @cnt &gt; 0

begin 

insert into #tempD ...

update #tempA set...

update #tempA set...

update #tempB set...

update #tempD set...

end

update #tempC set...

</update>
```

Somehow it seemed an transaction memory issue.
It's like a guessing for me to work with the XML statements, something that you wouldn't worry about if it's done by a stored procedure, just piling up all the SQLs in right order.

What's the best way to handle it in Java/myBatis? Is there anyway to catch this kind of exception?

Appreciate your time and help very much!

Glander

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding the settings to myBatisConfig.xml without code change though I still couldn't fully understand why.

```
           <settings>  
                <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="BATCH"/>  
          </settings>
```

Glander